# How to sort a text file using c#

Tags: c#

First I'm a very Beginner in c#, and Sorry for my english
I'm trying to sort myfile:"D:\Test.txt" by the number sfter the first "|"

**FROM :**
AVDT353|180   |||14/01/2021||
GSDF445|10      |||14/01/2021||
MLKLMK6|17023 |||14/01/2021||

**TO :**
GSDF445|10      |||14/01/2021||
AVDT353|180   |||14/01/2021||
MLKLMK6|17023 |||14/01/2021||

Answer (score 2):

First, load the text file. Then, create a list of strings by using line breaks as the  delimiter. Next, sort the lines using Linq, splitting after the | character. Finally, write the strings to file, putting each on a new line.

```
string contents = File.ReadAllText(@"D:\Test.tx");
var lines = contents.Split(Environment.NewLine).ToList();
var sorted = lines.OrderBy(l => l.Split("|")[1]).ToList();
// To update the content of the file:
File.WriteAllText(@"D:\Out.tx", string.Join(Environment.NewLine, sorted));
```

Comment: Wouldn't you need to do some kind of string-to-int conversion?

Comment: @RoyCohen we can sort strings lexicographically without converting to integers, conversion to int is unnecessary.

Comment: @AbdiBarid I've updated my answer to include writing to an output file.

Answer (score 0):

```
  void SortFile()
        {
            DirectoryInfo d = new DirectoryInfo(@"D:\Test");//Assuming Test is your Folder
            FileInfo[] Files = d.GetFiles("*.txt"); //Getting Text files
            string str = "";
            foreach (FileInfo file in Files)
            {
                int fileNo = Convert.ToInt32(file.Name.Split('|')[1]);
                for (int i = 0; i < Files.Length; i++)
                {
                    if (fileNo < Convert.ToInt32((Files[i].Name.Split('|')[1])))
                    {
                        //Add it to list or something
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```